# Return a hardcoded value if the result set follows a set of conditions (T-SQL-2000)

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

This question refers to the T-SQL compatible with MSSMS 2000.

Suppose the result set of a query Q always returns one column with 0, 1, or n records. I want a superquery W to return a value of 1 if the following conditions hold:

1. Only one record was retrieved in the subquery Q
2. The one record that was retrieved is 'c'

Q = SELECT DISTINCT status_code FROM Student

W(Q) = ?

Comment: What should W return if the conditions do not hold?

Answer (score 1):

If `Q` is a general query and not necessarily the one in your question, the putting `status_code` instead of `column` will do:

```
CASE WHEN  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Q) = 1
       AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Q WHERE column='c') = 1
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select if(count(*)=1 and status_code='c',1,0) as W from Student
```

(If you have 2 rows with `status_code='c'`, it will return `0`. Is it the expected output ?)